# Merging several taxonomy indexes for faceted search

Tags: lucene, facet, faceted-search

I am planing to change my existing lucene index to use the new facets introduced in lucene 3.4.0.

Unfortunately, documentation is still a bit sparse, so I could not find an answer to my question:

I create a relatively large index of 8 million books by dividing it into several smaller groups of documents, creating indices for them, and then joining them all together to one big index using `IndexWriter.addIndexes`.

This allows the work to be split among several threads or even computers.

I now would like to add faceted search capabilities to my index, but I have the following problem: How can I merge/add/join several taxonomy indexes as created by LuceneTaxonmyWriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question [on the lucene mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/201110.mbox/%3CCALfq-2T1t+zauu9v3mvMQjGEDGxwmgx6gsNAyiR91pvfVqXsRQ@mail.gmail.com%3E) and they pointed me to the class [TaxonomyMergeUtils](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_3_4_0/lucene/contrib/facet/src/examples/org/apache/lucene/facet/example/merge/TaxonomyMergeUtils.java?view=markup) that is part of the examples for the lucene-facets module.

This class contains the code needed to merge two indexes together with their taxonomy index.

Note: If you are using the maven package, the examples are not included, you will have to download the complete lucene package (and probably its source code as well) from the website.